# Passing React Native Input Field to State

Tags: react-native

**Background**

I am working with a `React Native` application and I have a login form. The login form `input` field is passing email to state on `button click`.
I am trying to console.log the email field. `this.state.email` but I keep getting email not defined.

I have removed the firebase functions to make it easier to read. But at the top of the form the `console.log` never succeeds.

**Examples**

These are the components I am working with.

**Input Component**

*This input component is to be used in LoginForm.*

```
class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      onChangeText: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View}>
        <Text>{this.props.label}</Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.value}
          onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginForm Component**

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
    };
  }

  signIn() {
    console.log(this.state.email);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.signIn()}
            btnTxt='Sign In'
          />
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

**Question**

What is the proper way to pass the input field "email" to `state` so I can use it in my `Firebase` Authentication function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code featured in your question, your `Input` component is calling `this.onChangeText` on `onChangeText`, this isn't referencing the same function you passed down as a `prop` from `LoginForm`.

```
class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      onChangeText: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.label}</Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.value}
          onChangeText={email => this.props.onChangeText(email)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```